# How can I see the IP addresses which are connected to a switch?

Tags: ip-address

I'm connected to a switch like my others business' computers. How can I get these IP addresses?

Of course, the switch is connected to a router and this to a modem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arp -a
```

Given an IP address, you should be able to find the MAC address of the corresponding host.

(Note that this will need to be run on a machine that is on the same IP subnet as the machine you are trying to find).

[Network Tracking Database](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netdbtracking/#screenshots**)

> > Description
>
> NetDB tracks all MAC addresses on your switches and ARP entries on
>   your network over time. It supports extensive switch, VLAN and vendor
>   code reports from a CLI or Web App. Can generate CSV reports, track
>   the usage of static addresses and much more.
>
> Features

Network User Tracking

Static Address Management

Unused Switchport Recovery

Security Audit Trail for all Network Devices

CLI and Web Interface, Easy Integration with Other Tools

[MORE HELP](https://serverfault.com/questions/10573/is-it-possible-to-match-an-internal-ip-address-to-a-switch-port)